# Ctrl Alt Del to Remote > Remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

[I already know how to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> to remote desktop.](http://stevenharman.net/how-to-ctrl--alt--del-in-remote-desktop)

But how do I send it to the second remote desktop. I'm remoting into the server and then within the remote session I'm doing the second remote to a desktop computer. So how do I get this key combination to the second remote computer (the desktop computer)?

I would remote directly into the second computer from here, but I don't know the ip address and the computer name won't resolve from here. These are secondary issues; my question here is how to send the Ctrl-Alt-Del to the remote > remote computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use the on screen keyboard and do it virtually!

Go to `Run` and type `osk.exe` then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> (in the RDC you want to do it on)

Comment: Beautiful! I used it on the server and sent the Ctrl+Alt+End to the second computer. It woke it up enough for me to work on it. Thanks much!

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows Server 2012 (i.e. Windows 8). It says To use the commands available when you press Ctrl+Alt+Del, click your user tile and choose an option. Problem is doing so doesn't give all the same options as Ctrl+Alt+Del does.

Comment: If are using a newer version of Windows for which this solution is ineffective and you need to change your password, you can use the "net user" command line utility.